# "markevery" Attribute in matplotlib plotting: Using values other than integer?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

`matplotlib` does not seem to accept values other than integer and list of the form (start, N) in my python compiler. Though it accepts floating values (which is supposed to approximately put the markers equally spaced along the line), it seems to be truncating the decimal part and uses the integral part as the argument. For all other input formats, it throws error. I am using Python 2.7.3 and matplotlib 1.1.1 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS. What is going wrong?

I take a small code as an example from the thread: [Plotting a curve with equidistant (arc-length) markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406758/plotting-a-curve-with-equidistant-arc-length-markers).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x*2) + np.sin(x + 1)

plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', markevery=xx)

plt.show()
```

- float value less than `1.0`: `markevery=0.05`

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try2.py", line 10, in <module>
    plt.savefig('try2.pdf')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 471, in savefig
  return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1185, in savefig
  self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2021, in print_figure
  **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1789, in print_pdf
  return pdf.print_pdf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2186, in print_pdf
  self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 898, in draw
  func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1997, in draw
  a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/lines.py", line 535, in draw
  vertices = tpath.vertices[startind::stride]
  ValueError: slice step cannot be zero
  ```
- `markevery=slice(start, end, N)`, every N-th marker, starting at point start, upto but not including point end, will be plotted: `markevery=slice(200,300,20)`

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try2.py", line 10, in <module>
  plt.savefig('try2.pdf')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 471, in savefig
  return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1185, in savefig
  self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2021, in print_figure
  **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1789, in print_pdf
  return pdf.print_pdf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2186, in print_pdf
  self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 898, in draw
  func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1997, in draw
  a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/lines.py", line 528, in draw
  startind, stride = markevery
  ValueError: too many values to unpack
  ```
- `markevery=[i, j, m, n]`, only markers at points i, j, m, and n will be plotted: `markevery=[200,250,300,350]`

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try2.py", line 10, in <module>
  plt.savefig('try2.pdf')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 471, in savefig
  return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1185, in savefig
  self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2021, in print_figure
  **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1789, in print_pdf
  return pdf.print_pdf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2186, in print_pdf
  self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 898, in draw
  func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1997, in draw
  a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/lines.py", line 528, in draw
  startind, stride = markevery
  ValueError: too many values to unpack
  ```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with that version of `matplotlib`. I am running 1.5.3 and the example works with non-integer values of `markevery`

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. Does it work fine with `markevery=slice(200,300,20)` and `markevery=[200,250,300,350]`?

Comment: Yes works with those as well.