# Python - Adding marker option to plot gives error

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I'm trying to add markers to my python plots using the mark every option. When I add this I get the following error: ValueError: too many values to unpack. I'm not sure what is causing it. Below is my code.

```
    temp = pd.read_csv(path+filename)
    temp=pd.DataFrame(temp).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

    fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1)
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)
    fig = plt.figure()
    markers_on=[887,1661,2631,3406,4714,5606,6880,8332,9751]
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)
    fig.suptitle('BC Attributes', fontsize=12)
    plt.subplot(3,1,1)
    plt.plot(temp.index,temp.BC_T_NODE0_CPU0_TEMP, marker='s', markevery=[887,1661,2631,3406,4714,5606,6880,8332,9751])
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Node0 CPU0 Temp')
    plt.subplot(3,1,2)
    plt.plot(temp.index, temp.BC_T_NODE0_CPU1_TEMP, marker='s', markevery=[887,1661,2631,3406,4714,5606,6880,8332,9751])
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Node0 CPU1 Temp')
    plt.subplot(3,1,3)
    plt.plot(temp.index, temp.BC_T_NODE1_CPU0_TEMP)
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Node1 CPU0 Temp')

    final_path="plots/CD/"
    fig.savefig(final_path+filename+'_1.png')
    plt.close(fig)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a self-contained example so that we can run without the data file? What version of matplotlib are you using? It seems that this has been an [issue in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544997/markevery-attribute-in-matplotlib-plotting-using-values-other-than-integer).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].